# How to take line wrap in account for JTextArea line counting?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm aware of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366776/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-jtextarea-including-those-caused-by-wrapp) showing a way to do but it leads to strange behaviors in my case and i'm wondering if there is no *simpler* way to do it.

I need to know the size my `JTextArea` will have after setting the text. Here is how i do at the moment:

```
tarea.getLineCount() * tarea.getRowHeight();
```

It works unless there is no line wrapping. I'd like to do the same calculation with line wrapping. Is there any to know when a line wrapping happen? This way i would only need to increment the current line count by one.

**EDIT:**

Here is (maybe) a solution i found. It's almost copy paste of [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing/screen_ScreenCoords.html) by @camickr.

```
int rowStartOffset = textComponent.viewToModel(new Point(0, 0));
int endOffset = textComponent.viewToModel(new Point(0, textComponent.getHeight()));

int count = 0; //used to store the line count
while (rowStartOffset < endOffset) {
    try {
        rowStartOffset = Utilities.getRowEnd(textComponent, rowStartOffset) + 1;
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
```

I made few tests with/without line wrapping enabled and it seemed to work.

Comment: If it is not for edit, use a multi-line `JLabel`.

Comment: someone will crucify you for that :-)

Comment: @mKorbel how seriously? what i did wrong? But thanks, i will consider using multiline jlabel.

Comment: uuuups (my bad) this was addresed to  @Andrew Thompson, but maybe he has important reason for his advice, :-) will ask for additional details, reason(s) :-), then this thread could be very nice with funny comments, aaach

Comment: and until this moment you can to read and try [Text Component Line Number](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/)  by @camickr

Comment: @mKorbel great! i think i might be able to extract the interesting part in my case out of this. Will edit the question if i run in further troubles :-)

Comment: OK. Edited the question with potential solution.

Comment: @mKorbel  It really depends on what the OP is trying to achieve.  If they do not clarify things like whether or not the area is for edit, I am just making guesses.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that so long as you haven't done called `setPreferredSize` on the Text Area, the `getPreferredSize` method should give you exactly what you're looking for without the hassle...

This is the reason why you shouldn't call `setPreferredSize` to do layout stuff.  Preferred size is supposed to be calculated by the component (when text is set for example).

Let me know if I'm missing the point ;)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CalculateTextAreaSize extends Box{

    public CalculateTextAreaSize(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        final JTextArea text = new JTextArea("I've\nGot\nA\nLovely\nBunch\nof\nCoconuts!\n");

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);

        add(pane);

        JButton button = new JButton("Set Text!");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                text.insert("Longish string - how long will it be?", text.getDocument().getLength());
                //The size it will be once everything is figured out
                System.out.println(text.getPreferredSize());
                //The size it is now because no rendering has been done
                System.out.println(text.getSize());
            }
        });
        add(button);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new CalculateTextAreaSize());
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```