# Disabling JTextArea resizing when user press Enter

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea, miglayout

I have a `JTextArea` that I would want the user to input address of a person. I know that valid address that the user will enter will not exceed `5 rows` and `10 columns`. So I have set it to `JTextArea (5,10)`. This way it works fine.

The problem is that when a user keeps on pressing `enter` more that 5 times, the text area will begin to resize. I do not want to put the text area in a `JScrollPane` since the text that the user will enter is not much for scrolling.

**Question**: How do we disable `JTextArea` from resizing when a user press `enter`?

Here is my code:

```
public class JTextAreaDemo {

private JFrame frame;

JTextAreaDemo(){
    frame= new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JLabel label=new JLabel("Address :");
    JTextArea address= new JTextArea(5,20);
    frame.add(label,"cell 0 0");
    frame.add(address, "cell 1 0");
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JTextAreaDemo();

        }});
    }
 }
```

Comment: Put it in a `JScrollPane`, it's resizing because it's preferred size is changing

Comment: Do you mean to say that when the user presses the enter button the 5th time It would be either replaced by a space or ignored?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, that is working. One thing, How do I avoid the cursor to move to the sixth row/line when user press enter?

Comment: @Blip Yes, when a user press enter the sixth time it should not do anything. It should not move to the sixth row/line.

Comment: ok but on pressing the enter 1st time the cursor moves to the 2nd row so when the enter is pressed 5th time the cursor moves to the 6th row. So your program should ignore 5th or more times the enter.

Comment: @Blip Yes, exactly what I want! How to achieve that? Please enlighten me.

Comment: please see my answer below

Comment: disable JTextArea from resizing when a user press enter? == new line in JTextArea :-)

Comment: Use a `DocumentFilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`DocumentFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html), for example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String... s) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    private JTextArea area;

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    private void init() {
        area = new JTextArea();
        ((AbstractDocument)area.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(getFilter(5));
        add(new JScrollPane(area));
    }

    private DocumentFilter getFilter(final int lineCount) {
        return new DocumentFilter(){

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                    String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                if(area.getLineCount()<=lineCount && area.getLineOfOffset(area.getCaretPosition())<lineCount)
                        if(text.contains("\n") && area.getLineCount()<lineCount)
                            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                        else if(!text.contains("\n"))
                            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, this is actually what I was looking for considering limiting the number of rows/lines.Thanks  so much.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, the filter shouldn't know about the text component, it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, but it just example. In that case we need method that count line numbers from `Document`. Also good catch about  line wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated, `DocumentFilter` can be used. I post this answer due to the elegant solution it offers.

```
public class JTextAreaDemo {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextArea address = new JTextArea(5, 20);

    JTextAreaDemo() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Address :");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(address, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        ((PlainDocument) address.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new LineFilter());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class LineFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

            if (address.getLineCount() < 5 || !string.contains("\n"))
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

            if (address.getLineCount() < 5 || !text.contains("\n"))
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new JTextAreaDemo();
    }
}
```

Although for user input overriding the method `insertString` won't be relevant, it is usually a good idea to cover all bases. Otherwise, it can be removed.

Note that there is no need for a `JScrollBar`.

**Edit:**

To allow @MadProgrammer to sleep quietly at night, the line counting is done (in a less elegant way) directly from the document:

```
@Override
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

    String content = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\n").matcher(content);
    int lines = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        lines++;
    }
    if (lines < 4 || !text.contains("\n"))
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
}
```

The `insertString` method can use the same code.

Comment: General rule of thumb, the filter shouldn't know about the UI/text component that's using it. Assuming that the text area doesn't have line wrapping enabled, then it becomes a relatively easy affair...if not...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I completely agree with the rule of thumb, although when the content (document side) affects the visuals (UI component side),  I think there is merit for this. I added a rule-of-thumb-friendly solution.

Comment: In case of line wrap it doesn't help you. Examine [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837605/how-to-take-line-wrap-in-account-for-jtextarea-line-counting)

Comment: @alex2410 The OP demonstrated that they are not using line wrap. I would have accounted for it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(X,Y))` so that the JTextArea will keep the dimension you set, and wont move at all !
You'll still need to put your JTextArea inside a `JScrollPane` thought.

Comment: Well, setting the preferred size alongside using the `JScrollPane` worked. Setting the preferred size alone could not make it, anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Giovanrich You're welcome, i edited my answer to your answer don't forget to close your question when you're done.

Comment: JTextArea and MigLayout hates setPreferredSize, this is about line/word wrap for JTextArea inside JScrollPane, otherwise  .... :-)

Comment: Well, I won't forget. How do I avoid it to move to sixth column? See @Blip second comment

Comment: I would avoid using something like this, as you don't control the many idiosyncrasies associated with fonts and font rendering

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should use an `InputVerifier` which will keep track of number of enters that have been entered in your `JTextArea` and when it reaches 4 then it should ignore the enters.

As you have pointed out in your comments `DocumentListener` would do the same and also `KeyListener` could do the same.

Comment: Doesn't `InputVerifer` only get notified on focus lost?  This won't stop the user from overflowing the field with text when the field is set to wrapping, for example

Comment: @MadProgrammer How about `DocumentListener` ? - Doesn't it save the purpose of tracking?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I really overlooked that **Yes that is true** and I am correcting my answer to accommodate for that that.

Comment: `DocumentFilter` might be preferred, then you just reject input you don't want without causing a mutation error