# How to get JTextPane line count

Tags: java, swing, count, line, jtextpane

So in `JTextArea` there is a `getLineCount()` is there something similar for `JTextPane`, because I could find anything. Perhaps there is a different way of obtaining that? I want to get the number of currently existing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (as you noted) no built-in way to find the number of lines in a `JTextPane`- this may be (although I see no official reference to support this) because of `JTextPane`'s ability to hold many different text styles in a single area, which would lead to some complications when finding the total number of lines.

You may be able to calculate the number of lines on your own, by keeping track of the text (and its style) that is presented inside of your `JTextPane`- you can then use other methods (perhaps `LineBreakMeasurer` (documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/font/LineBreakMeasurer.html))) to calculate the number of lines for each piece of text, and then sum up the total.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366776/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-jtextarea-including-those-caused-by-wrapp) for an example