# Counting line breaks in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

how can I count the number of line breaks in a JTextArea?
Is there a simple example? Any suggestions?

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366776/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-jtextarea-including-those-caused-by-wrapp):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextAreaLineCountDemo extends JPanel {                                          
    JTextArea textArea;      

    static Font f = new Font("Helvetiva", Font.ITALIC, 50);                                                                         

  public JTextAreaLineCountDemo() {                                                           
    super(new GridBagLayout());                                                               

    String inputStr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmo, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmo, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmo, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmo";
    textArea = new JTextArea(inputStr);     

    textArea.setEditable(false);                                                              
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);                                                               
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);                                                          

    // Add Components to this panel.                                                          
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();                                          
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;                                               

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;                                                         
    c.weightx = 1.0;                                                                          
    c.weighty = 1.0;                                                                          
    add(textArea, c);                                                                         

    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {                                             
      @Override                                                                               
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {   
          **textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 22));**
        System.out.println("Line count: " + countLines(textArea));                         
      }                                                                                       
    });                                                                                       
  }                                                                                           

  private static int countLines(JTextArea textArea) {
    AttributedString text = new AttributedString(textArea.getText());
    text.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, f);
    FontRenderContext frc = textArea.getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont())
        .getFontRenderContext();
    AttributedCharacterIterator charIt = text.getIterator();
    LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIt, frc);
    float formatWidth = (float) textArea.getSize().width;
    lineMeasurer.setPosition(charIt.getBeginIndex());

    int noLines = 0;
    while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < charIt.getEndIndex()) {
      lineMeasurer.nextLayout(formatWidth);
      noLines++;
    }

    return noLines;
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {                                                    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextAreaLineCountDemo");                                      
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                                     

    frame.add(new JTextAreaLineCountDemo());                                                  

    frame.pack();                                                                             
    frame.setVisible(true);                                                                   
  }                                                                                           

  public static void main(String[] args) {                                                    
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {                                   
      public void run() {                                                                     
        createAndShowGUI();                                                                   
      }                                                                                       
    });                                                                                       
  }                                                                                           
}
```