# How to make JTextArea occupy a max of 80% of the width in GridBagLayout in Java

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I am trying to make a chat window, but I can't seem to figure out how to make JTextArea occupy a maximum of 80% of the width space available in GridBagLayout. In other words, if the text seems to occupy the entire width of the window, it should only be able to occupy 80% of the width and just wrap the lines. Also, if the text is less than 80%, say 40%, then the JTextArea should only wrap 40% and not the whole 80%.

I'm using GridBagLayout and I've set GridBagConstraints weightx to 1.0 and the fill to HORIZONTAL with an inset of 40 either left or right, depends on the user. But I can't seem to make JTextArea to wrap the text and to allow it to use 80% of the width on the window if it needs it, otherwise wrap around the text.

Here is what my current chat window looks like:

Notice how the first entry by David should not occupy the entire width. It should only wrap the text.

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Below is the current code I wrote:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ChatWindow {

    private JFrame mMainFrame;

    public ChatWindow(List<ChatEntry> chatContentList) {
        // Create JFrame, set window size and center on screen.
        mMainFrame = new JFrame();
        mMainFrame.setTitle("Chat Window");
        mMainFrame.setSize(360, 600);
        mMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mMainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Create parent container JPanel for all other JComponents.
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(buildChatUI(chatContentList), gbc);

        // Add empty JPanel as an object to fill the empty space available.
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        mainPanel.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

        mMainFrame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new VerticalScrollPane(mainPanel)));
        mMainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel buildChatUI(List<ChatEntry> chatContentList) {
        JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
        chatPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        chatPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        for (ChatEntry chatEntry : chatContentList) {
            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(chatEntry.name);

            JTextArea contentTextArea = new JTextArea();
            contentTextArea.setText(chatEntry.content);
            contentTextArea.setOpaque(true);
            contentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
            contentTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            contentTextArea.setEditable(false);

            // Arrange each chat entry based on the user.
            if (chatEntry.type == 1) {
                contentTextArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            }
            else {
                contentTextArea.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            }

            gbc.insets.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            chatPanel.add(nameLabel, gbc);

            if (gbc.anchor == GridBagConstraints.WEST) {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.insets.set(0, 0, 0, 40);
                chatPanel.add(contentTextArea, gbc);
            }
            else {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.insets.set(0, 40, 0, 0);
                chatPanel.add(contentTextArea, gbc);
            }
        }

        return chatPanel;
    }


    /**
     * This class is used to make the JTextArea lines wrap every time the window
     * is resized. Without this, the JTextArea lines will not shrink back if the
     * parent window shrinks. This is achieved by returning true on getScrollableTracksViewportWidth();
     */
    private class VerticalScrollPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7477168367035025136L;

        public VerticalScrollPane() {
            this(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        }

        public VerticalScrollPane(LayoutManager lm) {
            super(lm);
        }

        public VerticalScrollPane(Component comp) {
            this();
            add(comp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                int orientation, int direction) {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                int orientation, int direction) {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Class structure for storing a single chat entry in a full conversation.
     */
    public static class ChatEntry {
        public String name;
        public String content;

        // For type 0=sent, 1=received.
        public int type;

        public ChatEntry(String name, String content, int type) {
            this.name = name;
            this.content = content;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Simulate a conversation between two users and pass it on to the
                // chat window to test the UI.
                List<ChatEntry> chatContentList = new LinkedList<>();
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Hey Lori, how are you?", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "Hi David, I'm good. What have you been up to?", 1));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "I've been super busy with work.", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Haven't had much free time to even go out to eat.", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "I know what you mean, I've had to work on projects after projects.", 1));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Let's make some time and go to lunch tomorrow!", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "That sounds great, let's do 12pm. I know a great food truck by my building.", 1));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Perfect, I'll meet you at the entrance of your building.", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "Awesome, see you tomorrow :)", 1));
                new ChatWindow(chatContentList);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kriegel, I was finally able to achieve what I desired. I was able to take some of the code you posted and implemented it another way.

Here is a screenshot of what everything now looks like:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class ChatWindow {

    private JFrame mMainFrame;

    public ChatWindow(List<ChatEntry> chatContentList) {
        // Create JFrame, set window size and center on screen.
        mMainFrame = new JFrame();
        mMainFrame.setTitle("Chat Window");
        mMainFrame.setSize(360, 600);
        mMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mMainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Create parent container JPanel for all other JComponents.
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        mainPanel.add(buildChatUI(chatContentList), gbc);

        // Add empty JPanel as an object to fill the empty space available.
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        mainPanel.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

        mMainFrame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new VerticalScrollPane(mainPanel)));
        mMainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel buildChatUI(List<ChatEntry> chatContentList) {
        JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
        chatPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        chatPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        for (ChatEntry chatEntry : chatContentList) {
            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(chatEntry.name);

            BubblePane bubble = new BubblePane(chatPanel, chatEntry.content);

            // Arrange each chat entry based on the user.
            if (chatEntry.type == 1) {
                bubble.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            }
            else {
                bubble.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            }

            gbc.insets.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.weightx = 1.0;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            chatPanel.add(nameLabel, gbc);

            if (gbc.anchor == GridBagConstraints.WEST) {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.insets.set(0, 0, 10, 40);
                chatPanel.add(bubble, gbc);
            }
            else {
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.insets.set(0, 40, 10, 0);
                chatPanel.add(bubble, gbc);
            }
        }

        return chatPanel;
    }

    private class BubblePane extends JTextArea {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6113801969569504295L;

        private int radius = 10;
        private int strokeThickness = 3;
        private int padding = strokeThickness / 2;
        private JPanel mParent;

        public BubblePane(JPanel parent, String text) {
            mParent = parent;

            setOpaque(false);
            setLineWrap(true);
            setWrapStyleWord(true);
            setEditable(false);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            setText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            int x = padding + strokeThickness;
            int width = getWidth() - (strokeThickness * 2);
            int bottomLineY = getHeight() - strokeThickness;
            g2d.fillRect(x, padding, width, bottomLineY);
            g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeThickness));
            RoundRectangle2D.Double rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, padding,
                    width, bottomLineY, radius, radius);
            Area area = new Area(rect);
            g2d.draw(area);


            int lc = countLines(this);
            GridBagLayout gbl = (GridBagLayout) mParent.getLayout();
            GridBagConstraints constraints = gbl.getConstraints(this);
            if (lc == 1) {
                if (constraints.fill == GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL) {
                    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                    gbl.setConstraints(this, constraints);
                    this.setSize(
                            getFontMetrics(getFont()).stringWidth(getText()) + 
                            this.getBorder().getBorderInsets(this).left +
                            this.getBorder().getBorderInsets(this).right, 
                            getHeight() +
                            this.getBorder().getBorderInsets(this).top + 
                            this.getBorder().getBorderInsets(this).bottom);
                }
            } else {
                if (constraints.fill == GridBagConstraints.NONE) {
                    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    gbl.setConstraints(this, constraints);

                }
            }

            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

        private int countLines(JTextArea textArea) {
            AttributedString text = new AttributedString(textArea.getText());
            FontRenderContext frc = textArea.getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont())
                    .getFontRenderContext();
            AttributedCharacterIterator charIt = text.getIterator();
            LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIt, frc);
            float formatWidth = (float) textArea.getSize().width;
            lineMeasurer.setPosition(charIt.getBeginIndex());

            int noLines = 0;
            while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < charIt.getEndIndex()) {
                lineMeasurer.nextLayout(formatWidth);
                noLines++;
            }

            return noLines;
        }
    }


    /**
     * This class is used to make the JTextArea lines wrap every time the window
     * is resized. Without this, the JTextArea lines will not shrink back if the
     * parent window shrinks. This is achieved by returning true on getScrollableTracksViewportWidth();
     */
    private class VerticalScrollPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7477168367035025136L;

        public VerticalScrollPane() {
            this(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        }

        public VerticalScrollPane(LayoutManager lm) {
            super(lm);
        }

        public VerticalScrollPane(Component comp) {
            this();
            add(comp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                int orientation, int direction) {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect,
                int orientation, int direction) {
            return 100;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class structure for storing a single chat entry in a full conversation.
     */
    public static class ChatEntry {
        public String name;
        public String content;

        // For type 0=sent, 1=received.
        public int type;

        public ChatEntry(String name, String content, int type) {
            this.name = name;
            this.content = content;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Simulate a conversation between two users and pass it on to the
                // chat window to test the UI.
                List<ChatEntry> chatContentList = new LinkedList<>();
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Hey Lori, how are you?", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "Hi David, I'm good. What have you been up to?", 1));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "I've been super busy with work.", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Haven't had much free time to even go out to eat.", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "I know what you mean, I've had to work on projects after projects.", 1));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Let's make some time and go to lunch tomorrow!", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "That sounds great, let's do 12pm. I know a great food truck by my building.", 1));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("David", "Perfect, I'll meet you at the entrance of your building.", 0));
                chatContentList.add(new ChatEntry("Lori", "Awesome, see you tomorrow :)", 1));
                new ChatWindow(chatContentList);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a time consuming way to relayout the TextAreas when the window is resized. I've added ComponentListeners per ChatEntry that will resize the entries TextArea. That's just proof of concept and can be improved performancewise.

Try the following and reduce the windows width and then slowly broaden it to see the effect. It resembles what you pictured as your goal. I havent managed to achieve that layout iimediately when the window opens. While slowly broadening the window works quite well, if you move too fast then the lines may appear too wide due to caching inside the JDK code.

Anyway, thought I share my experiment, maybe it helps you find a way to deal with it. I assume you might have to implement your own layout manager to fully accomplish your stated goals and circumnvent the observed caching.

The way to count lines inside a TextArea is taken from another StackOverflow question: [How to count the number of lines in a JTextArea, including those caused by wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366776/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-jtextarea-including-those-caused-by-wrapp)

```
public JPanel buildChatUI(List<ChatEntry> chatContentList) {
    final JPanel chatPanel = new JPanel();
    chatPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    chatPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    for (ChatEntry chatEntry : chatContentList) {
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(chatEntry.name);

        final JTextArea contentTextArea = new JTextArea();
        contentTextArea.setText(chatEntry.content);
        contentTextArea.setOpaque(true);
        contentTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        contentTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        contentTextArea.setEditable(false);
        chatPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                int lc = countLines(contentTextArea);
                GridBagLayout gbl = (GridBagLayout) chatPanel.getLayout();
                GridBagConstraints constraints = gbl.getConstraints(contentTextArea);
                if (lc == 1) {
                    if (constraints.fill == GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL) {
                        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                        gbl.setConstraints(contentTextArea, constraints);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (constraints.fill == GridBagConstraints.NONE) {
                        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                        gbl.setConstraints(contentTextArea, constraints);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { }
            @Override public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { }
            @Override public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) { }
        });

        // Arrange each chat entry based on the user.
        if (chatEntry.type == 1) {
            contentTextArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        }
        else {
            contentTextArea.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        }

        gbc.insets.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        chatPanel.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        if (gbc.anchor == GridBagConstraints.WEST) {
            gbc.insets.set(0, 0, 0, 40);
            chatPanel.add(contentTextArea, gbc);
        }
        else {
            gbc.insets.set(0, 40, 0, 0);
            chatPanel.add(contentTextArea, gbc);
        }
    }

    return chatPanel;
}

/**
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366776/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-jtextarea-including-those-caused-by-wrapp
 * @param textArea the text area of interest
 * @return number of lines in text area
 */
private static int countLines(JTextArea textArea) {
    AttributedString text = new AttributedString(textArea.getText());
    FontRenderContext frc = textArea.getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont())
            .getFontRenderContext();
    AttributedCharacterIterator charIt = text.getIterator();
    LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIt, frc);
    float formatWidth = (float) textArea.getSize().width;
    lineMeasurer.setPosition(charIt.getBeginIndex());

    int noLines = 0;
    while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < charIt.getEndIndex()) {
        lineMeasurer.nextLayout(formatWidth);
        noLines++;
    }

    return noLines;
}
```