# What font in Swing looks the same in all OS?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I use Netbeans 7.0 with JDK6 under Windows 7 to design the user interface of my Java application. I apply System look and feel. But it looks the way I want in Windows but differs in MacOS  and even worse, it looks different in different window managers in Linux (LXDE, GNOME, KDE, XFCE).

By different I mean the fonts look and their size. In Windows, if a label looks "v 1.23", it looks like "v ..." in other OSes because the fonts become bigger in that OS and the JLabel do not have enough place to show. This happens in several places.

I don't want to increase the label width. I want the label to look the same in that given width in all OS. By default, Netbeans uses the font Tahoma 11pt on my pc. I think it's not available in all OSes so the other OSes use different font.

Is Arial a common font?

Should I change the font of every element to Arial manually? Or any other options?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't and shouldn't have to. Design your UI such that it doesn't break when the font (of all things - next you'll require that the window stays at the upper left corner?) or text changes slightly. Think of i18n or simply a designer having a good idea.

Comment: See [Physical and Logical Fonts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to window managers there is a lot more to it than just font size, for instance the width between 2 controls are handled differently in gnome & KDE. when it comes down to using the same font size across all platforms you can use `Sans Serif` font, this is available in all the OS'es I've worked with.

it would also be better (if you can't find serif in an OS where you want to run your app) you can download a font (free ones from [GNU Free Fonts](http://www.gnu.org/s/freefont/)).

when it comes to setting the font sizes & the fonts, why don't you try using a theme & set the font there... 
you can use the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` method to change themes.
here is a link on [Look & Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Comment: Serif is not a font. It is a font category. When you tell Java to use Serif, it picks a specific serif font on your computer. There will definitely be variety from OS to OS.

Comment: @Anantha Sharma Thanks for you answer. I plan to use Nimbus Theme.

Answer (score 8):

Instead, use a [layout manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and a [logical font family](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html). This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979795/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-rows-and-columns-in-each-row-a-text-takes-in-a-j/5998117#5998117) with the `Font` below adds 24-point italic serif text to the center of a (default) `BorderLayout` to achieve a pleasing result on disparate platforms.

```
ta.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 24));
```

Mac OS X:

[image: Mac]

Windows 7:

[image: Windows]

Ubuntu Linux:

[image: Linux]

Comment: Sadly, I just noticed that Ubuntu's notion of "Serif" looks disturbingly "SansSerif". :-)

Comment: If you're worried about the "Serif" string changing, `Font.SERIF` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I've found it because I was looking for a solution.
And my solution is: use DejaVu fonts.
The Java dialog font looks different in Linux and Windows, but DejaVuSans 12 is very like the dialog font in Linux and looks the same in Windows (in Windows 8.1 at least).
My code:

```
...
static Font dejaVuSans;
static final String resPath = "<classpath>/resources/"; // no leading "/"
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* See:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434845/setting-the-default-font-of-swing-program
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361947/how-to-get-getclass-getresource-from-a-static-context
     */
    dejaVuSans = null;
    Font f;
    try {
        InputStream istream = <ClassName>.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            resPath + "DejaVuSans.ttf");
        dejaVuSans = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream);
        f = dejaVuSans.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 12);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        f = null;
    }
    if (f == null)
        f = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    java.util.Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object key = keys.nextElement();
        Object value = UIManager.get (key);
        if (value != null && value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource)
            UIManager.put (key, f);
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, if DejaVuSans.ttf is not embedded in the jar file you can import it at runtime. See [How do you import a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364787/how-do-you-import-a-font).

Answer (score 0):

Lucida Sans Regular is always bundled with Java but I don't think it will solve the problem that some text/labels go out of format. That depends also on the users's screen resulotion.