# Resize every UI element in the application

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem , every UI element is too small if I use default Fonts etc. How do I change font for every possible UI element, default row heigth for JTable ?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434845/setting-the-default-font-of-swing-program-in-java

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Use a `BigLookAndFeel` (a custom PLAF).

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html)  class.Try with put() method.Use JTables getPrefferedSize() to get default size

Comment: UIManager.put(“TextField.font”, new Font(“Dialog”, Font.BOLD, 14))  like this you have to do the same for other ui components and then do a SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(your UI Frame)