# Issue with the size of japanese characters (hiragana / katakana / kanji)

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm trying to realize a simple software that should use both standard european characters and japanese characters (hiragana / katakana / kanji), but I'm experiencing the following problem. I would like to make the japanese text bigger, but if I set a higher number as font dimension I start seeing squares instead of characters, while if I keep standard dimension everything is fine. 
How can I see bigger japanese fonts?

Comment: I almost forgot. I'm programming in Java, I'm showing a GUI using swing, the text is saved in UTF-8 format. In case this helps :)

Comment: I'm now showing text in a simple text field, but I can switch to another component in case it is necessary or better..

Comment: http://blog.lingualift.com/10-beautiful-japanese-fonts/

Comment: I don't know why, but I was thinking that installing the fonts would automatically make them selected in my software (kind of automatic best choice). I already had Meiryo installed since I'm on a Windows 8 Platform, I just had to choose it in my IDE. Anyway, just write a normal answer if you want it to be selected as final answer. Thank you for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a font able to display Japanese characters,

for example [one of this](http://blog.lingualift.com/10-beautiful-japanese-fonts/),

and then set it to be used by your components, [replacing the default one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7434845/1654265) (that is dependent on your Operative System / Look and Feel).