# Is there something like fontello/bootstrap glyphicons for java swing?

Tags: java, swing, glyphicons

I want to use glyphicons in JButton and I wonder if there are is some alternative for Java Swing. If not is there is a way I can use fontello in my Java project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glyphicons use a font to display icons, each icon being a character in the font.

Therefore it is simple to use them in JButtons.

1. Create a swing Font for the glyphicon font.
2. Set the font on your JButton.
3. Set the button label to the character of a glyphicon icon. The characters codes can be found for example in bootstrap.css.

Here is a detailed explanation using [fontawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177348/font-awesome-with-swing) instead of glyphicons but the technique is the same.