# Awesome Fonts: "pr0blem reading font data" in Java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, font-awesome

My goal is to be able to use awesome fonts an a Java GUI. For that matter I searched and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177348/font-awesome-with-swing).

I chose the second answer to import fontawesome-webfont.ttf with an InputStream. I tailored the code to my needs because I do not need a method for my purpose.

But when it comes to testing it, I get the error: "Problem reading font data" in the line:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

---

**This is the problematic code:**

```
try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:/Users/Prak01/Documents/EclipseWorkspace/Zeiterfassung/fontawesome-webfont.ttf")) {
    try {
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24f);
        TextfieldFont = new JTextField("&#xf0c0;");
        TextfieldFont.setFont(font);
    } catch (FontFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

I believe that I did everything according to the rules. The data path is correct. Could it be possible that it is because of the...

```
this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream();
```

because I changed it from:

```
TestFontAwsome.class.getResourceAsStream();
```

but I believe that it should work with `this.getClass()` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistakenly assumed that the argument to [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) is supposed to be a file name.  It is not a file name;  it’s a *relative URL* which is resolved against each entry in the classpath.  Generally, this means it should be a path in the same .jar file.

If you want to load a Font directly from a File, don’t use getResourceAsStream.  Just open it as a file:

```
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
    Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/Prak01/Documents/EclipseWorkspace/Zeiterfassung/fontawesome-webfont.ttf")))) {
```

Note:  You don’t need two `try` blocks.  A try-with-resources statement is allowed to have a `catch` block:

```
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
    Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/Users/Prak01/Documents/EclipseWorkspace/Zeiterfassung/fontawesome-webfont.ttf")))) {

    // ...

} catch (FontFormatException e1) {
    // ...
}
```