# resize showInputDialog textarea?

Tags: java, swing, groovy, jframe, joptionpane

I'm working with Groovy / Java with Swing, and trying to build `JOptionPane` `showInputDialog` frame, which pops to user, and takes user input in text field.

Yes it's simple. But my problem is that `showInputDialog` text area is by default quite small, and for usability I want it to be bigger.

Does anyone know how to resize textarea?

Example:
This is what I get
[small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOK5d.png)

[image]

But this is what I want
[big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4CSG.png)

[image]

Comment: Note: You seem to use the terms textfield & textarea interchangeably, but they are entirely separate components. The first is for a single line of text, the 2nd is for multi-line text. Please use terms more carefully, and [edit] this question to remove all references to the one that is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have success with [Sergiy Medvynskyy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1989769/sergiy-medvynskyy)'s answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913923/change-size-e-font-joptionpane) question, or at least use it in some way;

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("MESSAGE");
label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

Since `JOptionPane` accepts a JLabel as parameter, you could experiment a bit by trying to resize that one, and then just passing it on.

**Edit:**

Assuming you are using Swing, this code should work.
 (You might have to experiment a bit to reach your desired size/layout)

```
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));

        JPanel jp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Example Prompt Message!");
        jl.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));

        jp.add(jl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jp.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, jp);
```

Result should be something similiar to this. (You can change the dialogue type too of course, though `showInputDialog` probably won't work, due to it already having a default input line.)

[image: Sample Output with re-sized text field]

Comment: Yes that works on showMessageDialog, but not whit showInputDialog

Comment: [Seeing how it utilizes the same parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)), I doubt it'd be any different.

Comment: @AscendedKitten the link is broken

Comment: Works just fine for me. Try that one? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog

Comment: It just don't work for me:( If It works for you? can pass code?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: This answer doesnt explain how to get what the user inputted

Answer (score 0):

Building on AscendedKittens answer, this shows how you actually get the inputted data back.

```
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    tf.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Example Prompt Message!");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(tf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel);
    if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
    {
        System.out.println(tf.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The text inside *JOptionPane.showInputDialog* is considered a **TextField** . You can solve this problem by using the *UIManager.put* method .

```
UIManager.put("TextField.font", 
         new FontUIResource(new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,21)));
```

Changing the font of the letters will make the TextField considerably longer too , so if you want to avoid this you can do this :

```
UIManager.put("TextField.margin", 
             new InsetsUIResource(0,0,0,-100));
```