# The JOptionPane in eclipse is extremely tiny

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, joptionpane

I am using **Eclipse Photon 2018** and making a simple project using **Java**.
I started to use `JOptionPane` and for some reason - the size is tiny, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

**My code:**

*Main.java:*

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Messageable ui = new GrapghicalUI();
        String res = ui.getString("what is your name? ");
        ui.showMessage("hi" +res);
    }

}
```

*ConsuleUI.java:*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleUI implements Messageable{
    private Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        return s.next();
    }

}
```

*GraphicalUI.java:*

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GrapghicalUI implements Messageable {

    @Override
    public void showMessage(String str) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String msg) {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(msg);
    }

}
```

*Messageable:*

```
public interface Messageable {
    void showMessage(String str);
    String getString(String msg);
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913923/how-do-you-change-the-size-and-font-of-a-joptionpane

Comment: Why do you have 4 classes to display a simple JOptionPane? When  problem solving learn to simplify the problem. That way you know if the problem is related to your overall design or something else. So try just displaying the JOptionPane from the main() method to see if you have the same problem. Also, all Swing components should be created and modified on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. So you need to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possibly a problem with Windows application scaling on a high DPI monitor. Usually it can be fixed by enabling "Override High DPI scaling behavior" under the compatibility tab of the properties of an executable file.

This question was posted on Microsoft support and can be found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/dialog-box-too-small-in-windows-10-computer/6e503429-2b8a-47f0-80b5-3e5df5820c10?tab=AllReplies#tabs&page=3)

Since the dialog you see is from a separate program from the IDE itself, the scaling won't match as it has nothing to do with it. However, setting the above mentioned option will most likely not be very helpful as the executable gets replaced each time you build/compile it.