# How to change fonts of all components

Tags: java, swing, fonts, uimanager

How can I change the font of all components that are displayed in my java application?

I tried it using the UIManager

```
UIManager.put("TextField.font",  new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 11));
UIManager.put("Label.font",  new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 11));
UIManager.put("ComboBox.font",  new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 11))
```

Oddly enough this changed the font of the textfield but did not work for JLabels or JComboBoxes

Then I tried to set the font by looping over all keys the UIManager knows:

```
public static void setUIFont(FontUIResource f) {
    Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object key = keys.nextElement();
        Object value = UIManager.get(key);
        if (value instanceof FontUIResource) {
            FontUIResource orig = (FontUIResource) value;
            Font font = new Font(f.getFontName(), orig.getStyle(), f.getSize());
            FontUIResource fontUIResource = new FontUIResource(font);
            UIManager.put(key, fontUIResource);
            UIManager.getDefaults().put(key, fontUIResource);
            UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getDefaults().put(key, fontUIResource);
        }
    }
}
```

This code did not work at all.

I must say that I use Synthetica as LookAndFeel... so I don't know how that interferes with my manuell settings via UIManager.

Comment: [Moreover it enables you to modify existing Themes and to create your own look and feel only by editing a XML-based configuration file - you don't have to write complex Java-GUI-Code.](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/)

Comment: voting tgo close as off-topics

Answer (score 0):

I think you can update [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7434935/3850595) from [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313137/romain-hippeau) as follows:

```
public static void setUIFont (java.awt.Font f){
    java.util.Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object key = keys.nextElement();
      Object value = UIManager.get (key);
      if (value != null && value instanceof java.awt.Font)
        UIManager.put (key, f);
      }
}
```

Then use it with your `Font` like this:

```
setUIFont (new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 11));
```

Comment: *"`new java.awt.Font("Arial Unicode MS"..`"*  For greater cross-platform support, use logical fonts (e.g. `Font.SANS_SERIF` as opposed to `"Arial Unicode MS"`).

Comment: agree... but I just used `Font` in the original question....

Comment: It didn't work. I debugged the code and the values are written for each component, but the UI is still the same. Is it possible that Synthetica ignores those manuell settings?

Comment: This is a copy-paste answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7434935/1803551), you just changed the name and number a bit.

Comment: @user1803551 actually I use it in one of my apps, and YES, I guess I took it from there cause my upvote is still there...  where is the problem?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered).

Comment: My bad, agree and [corrected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078/278325).  @user1803551

Comment: Alright. Now why not just vote to close as duplicate?

Comment: Well, it was closed as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own components like:

```
public class MyJButton extends JButton {

    public MyJButton(){
        setFont(FontClass.getBasicFont());
    }

}

public class MyJTextArea extends JTextArea {

    public MyJTextArea (){
        setFont(FontClass.getBasicFont());
    }

}
.
.
.
```

And then create this class which holds all your fonts properties like:

```
public class FontClass(){

    private static final String BASIC_FONT_FACE = "Arial";

    private static final String BASIC_FONT_SIZE = 12;

    public static Font getBasicFont(){
        return new Font(BASIC_FONT_FACE, Font.PLAIN, BASIC_FONT_SIZE);
    }

}
```

I suppose that this is the primitive way, but it can be good if you want to save 
these values in your DB