# How to get getclass().getResource() from a static context?

Tags: java, url, getresource

I have a function where I am trying to load a file to a `URL` object, because the example project said so.

```
public class SecureFTP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException , ClassNotFoundException, SQLException , JSchException, SftpException{
        File file = new File("/home/xxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys");
        URL keyFileURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file);
```

I tried using `SecureFTP.class.getResource`, but it still could not compile it.

I am fairly new to Java, so I know I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can't compile because `getResource` takes a resource name (a `String`, and not a `File`) as parameter, in order to load a resource using the class loading mechanism (from the classpath). Using it with a `File` makes no sense. If you want to open a file, just use a `FileInputStream` or a `FileReader`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29, and include the compiler error message next time you have such a question.

Answer (score 74):

The main method is a static method, so trying to access `this` (= the current Object) will not work.
You can replace that line by

```
URL keyFileURL = SecureFTP.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/home/xxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys");
```

Comment: That's precisely what the OP tried. Read the question more carfully. The problem is that he's passing a File rather than a STring to the method.

Comment: You are right. I corrected my answer. However, the OP tried SecureFTP.class.getResource, without the getClassLoader call

Comment: Your method will not work: getResource doesn't load resources from the file system, and resource names don't start with a /. Read my answer.

Answer (score 28):

From: [How to call getClass() from a static method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275499/how-to-call-getclass-from-a-static-method-in-java)

> Just use TheClassName.class instead of getClass().

Answer (score 22):

Old question but this hasn't been said yet. You can do this from a static context:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
classLoader.getResource("filename");
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. (I've even upvoted it). However, when tried to run `mvn exec:java` it couldn't locate the resource. Using the other answers here (`SecureFTP.class.getClassLoader().getResource`) solved it.

Answer (score 5):

```
SecureFTP.class.getClassLoader().getResource(<<your resource name>>);
```

Should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way so that it works EITHER from a static method or an instance method:

```
public static String loadTestFile(String fileName) {
    File file = FileUtils.getFile("src", "test", "resources", fileName);
    try {
        return FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error loading test file: " + fileName, e);
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```