# How to make a maven project recognize a file from its own directory instead of working directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I currently have two projects:

```
api-test
    ...
    /config/config.json
    ...
```

and

```
ui-test
    ...
    /config/config.json
    ...
```

In eclipse, I am adding api-test in the build path of ui-test, so that api-test is the dependency of ui-test.

However the build failed, because api-test is looking for the config.json located in api-test/config/config.json by calling:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/config/config.json"
```

which does not exist in ui-test project.

the two config.json include different contents - what would be the best solution to let each project refer to their own config.json while ui-test is referring to api-test project?

Comment: Although it's not advisable, you can simply point to a file using its full path

Comment: Not that this would solve the path issue but why do you "_add api-test in the build path of ui-test_"? Why don't you add _api-test_ as dependency to the POM of _ui-test_ ?

Comment: If you mean to add the api-test.jar into POM of ui-test, I tried, but the jar does not contain the config.json so I sill will see the same error. Should jar file pack the json file?

Comment: Leave the `json` files aside for a moment and get familiar with Maven's dependency concept(s) in [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) and [POM Reference, Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies). You have a project (=library, =jar) `api-test`. Your other project `ui-test` depends on `api-test`, so the clean Maven way is to add `api-test` as dependency in `ui-test`'s POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the files into the projects' `src/main/resources` directories as suggested by [Maven's Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). You can use relative paths to access these resources then.

See [How to get file resource from Maven src/test/resources/ folder in JUnit test?](http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/07/how-to-get-file-resource-from-maven-srctestresources-folder-in-junit-test/) For instance:

> **Test file existence**
>
> ```
> @Test
> public void testStreamToString() {
>   assertNotNull("Test file missing", getClass().getResource("/sample.txt"));
>   ...
> }
> ```

Comment: If I move the config.json from api-test to within ui-test project, then ui-test project will end up with 2 config.json, which doesn't make sense?

Comment: @jamesdeath123 Where did I write to do so?

Comment: You mentioned put the files into the projects' src/main/resources, and I assume what you mean is by put the api-test's config.json to the ui-test's src/main/resources folder? Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @jamesdeath123 That's not what I meant. I wrote "project**s'**" ... "director**ies**", i.e. put each file into `src/main/resources` of the project it belongs to.

Comment: I see! Unfortunately the config class that is reading that file is a singleton's static method, and cannot reference to the the non-static getClass()...

Comment: @jamesdeath123 Are you able to work with a search engine of your choice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/how-can-i-get-a-resource-content-from-a-static-context and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361947/how-to-get-getclass-getresource-from-a-static-context took me 5 seconds to find.