# Corrupted (cached?) fonts in java swing

Tags: java, swing, memory-corruption

My machine seems to be experiencing some weird issues with java swing.

[image]

This sort of thing happens with other programs as well but the corruption goes away with scrolling or highlighting the text. What could be causing this and why doesn't java go the same? All the characters seem to be cached so that when a character gets corrupted, all of the characters of the same type have the same corruption (not true of anything but java swing).

I have been googling around for this sort of issue but most of them only suggest issues with graphics drivers and settings for windows... (I am running kubuntu)

Side note: Sorry if this doesn't belong here. Didn't really know where else to ask.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem you illustrate.

Comment: @trashgod, unfortunately all I can really suggest for reproducing the problem is to open any java application on my computer. I can give you details about what is installed and hardware details but reproducing this issue seems more likely to be drivers or hardware failure.

Comment: I am honestly at a loss for why this might be happening and I have a degree in the field that should know... (I think). If its hardware then I understand it but maybe not well enough to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the *many* possible causes,

- Verify that *all* correctly synchronized Java Swing programs using standard font families with the default Look & Feel exhibit this behavior; if not, it may very well be a driver problem.
- Investigate whether the Ubuntu video driver permits alterations similar to the one required in [this Windows case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22737535/230513).
- Try a [different window manager](https://askubuntu.com/q/162516).
- Try a [different Look & Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513).

Comment: It seems to be a mesa thing, I ended up compiling my own version that massively reduced how bad the fonts seemed to get messed up.

Comment: Glad you made progress; I try to stick to the logical font families and use a layout manager, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7189029/230513).