# setBounds of JComponent to pixel width of a string

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent, absolutelayout

I have this inner class:

```
private class Plats extends JComponent{
    private String namn;
    Plats(int x, int y, String n){
        namn=n;
        setBounds(x-10, y-10, 150, 40);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 20, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(namn, 0, 34);
    }
    public boolean contains(int x, int y){
        return x<20 && x>0 && y<20 && y>0;
    }
}
```

I want to set the bounds of the component to the width of the string that the constructor gets, but I can only get it to work if I do it inside the paintComponent method since I need the graphics object. It feels wrong to do it in the paintComponent method since every time the component has to be repainted it will set the bounds again and I only want to do it once when it is created.

Suggestions how I can solve this? Or should I just do it in the paintComponent anyway?, it works but I doesnt feel like a nice solution :( ?

Comment: A component should not set it's own bounds!  Leave it to the layout.

Comment: *"I want to set the bounds of the component to the width of the string that the constructor gets"* As an aside.  `JLabel` (with layouts) has that built in.  Why are you trying to reinvent the lever?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use `AbsoluteLayout`, only if is there really important reason, use proper `LayoutManager`,

your `JComponent` should be returns `PreferredSize` (notice `PreferredSize` isnot accepted by all of standard or custom LayoutManagers) to its parent or container, for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CustomComponent extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomComponent() {
        setTitle("Custom Component Graphics2D");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void display() {
        CustomComponents cc = new CustomComponents();
        /*cc.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
                setSize(Math.min(getPreferredSize().width, getWidth()),
                        Math.min(getPreferredSize().height, getHeight()));
            }
        });*/
        add(cc, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        CustomComponents cc1 = new CustomComponents();
        add(cc1, BorderLayout.EAST);

        pack();
        // enforces the minimum size of both frame and component
        setMinimumSize(getSize());
        //setMaximumSize(getMaximumSize());
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomComponent main = new CustomComponent();
        main.display();
    }
}

class CustomComponents extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im so sorry but I really have no idea what you're trying to tell me. I dont want a LayoutManager because I need to place them exactly where I click with my mouse

Comment: @Ceilingbat `I need to place them exactly where I click with my mouse` finally some clear info :-), please edit your question with this one and another if exists....

Comment: *"I need to place them exactly where I click with my mouse"*  Use a (custom) `WhereverIDropThisSh*t` ***layout.***  Positioning logic should not be inside a component, it is just the wrong place for it.

Comment: I think that is a little too hard for me, Im currently taking my second programming course at university, but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: *"I think that is a little too hard for me"*  What is?  Programming - drop it; logic, drop university; communicating your point to people; become a hermit.

Answer (score 1):

Even without a graphics context, you can use either `TextLayout` or `FontRenderContext` to find the bounds; the two are compared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513). Because you extend `JComponent`, your component *should* override the `getXxxSize()` methods, as shown in mKorbel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194351/230513).

Comment: Oops, sorry about the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Font#getStringBounds(String str, FontRenderContext frc) to get a bounding rectangle of the string in the form of the said Font. From there you can return the width and height.

[Font Java 1.6 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)

Comment: To do that I would need to get the graphics object and then get the FontRenderContext, I don't think I can get the graphics object outside of the paintComponent method