# How to use FontMetrics?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, jpanel, fontmetrics

Can someone explain to me how to use FontMetrics in a JPanel?  I need to figure out the width and height in pixels of a String when using drawString() to paint it on a JPanel

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Examples may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513).

Comment: Neither of these answers seem helpful, and I have the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a Graphics object as your method's input variable. or, you can use getFontMetrics() method of your JFrame or JPanel.

for example to get a character's width:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
int charWidth = frame.getFontMetrics( frame.getFont() ).charWidth() ;
```