# Multi line label/area/pane in Java with Justified text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextarea, jtextpane

I have an interesting task. Consider a `String content`with unknown length. I'd like to display `content` with a `Font font` with [Justified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_%28typesetting%29) text. I need to know what `height` this would take up if I specify the `width`. I want to display this text in the middle of the screen but it must have a width of `width`.

Hence, I would like to do something such as the following.

```
//create a JTextPane or JTextArea
pane.setText(content);
pane.setFont(font);
//set the width of the pane here
//get the height of the full text block if its justified
pane.setLocation(screenWidth/2 - width/2, screenHeight/2, height/2);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Justified: Left? Right? Center? Fill? See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5979795/230513) on `TextLayout`.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_(typesetting) to learn what "Justified" text is.

Comment: Are you specifying the width? It looks like you need to compute the width based on the font size and String to display.

Comment: I'm specifying the width, and need to determine the height.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_(typesetting)

Comment: by default `JLabel.setText("<html><p style='text-align:justify'> + your text here + </html>")`, same / similair with `JTextPane/Editor`, no idea how to determine `numbers of rows` for `JLabel`, `JTextPane/Editor` returns that by default, no idea where is your issue

Comment: can you fill in the code I'm missing then? I'm not following completely what you're saying. keep in mind I'm trying to use a specific font.

Comment: I' sure that must be solved by ([@StanislavL](http://stackoverflow.com/users/301607/stanislavl)) or ([@Andrew Thompson)](http://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson)) a few times here

Comment: @mKorbel  Thanks for the accolades, but why did you delete *your* answer?  Seems to me your suggestion of `style='text-align:justify'` achieves the stated goal perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, justification is done the other way around.

The text has a fixed height, and you adjust the width of the text in one of the following ways:

- Add spaces between the words.  Easier, but not visually appealing.
- Add space between the letters.  This is called [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

If you adjust the height so that the width is correct, every line in your text will have a different height.